# How to optimize C# code if need display 32 stream media information in a form developed with C#

Tags: c#, forms, optimization, video-streaming

There are more than 32 stream media data needed to display in one form at the sametime.  But I found that it is a great challenge, a lot of CPUs were used to process decoder task.  So the form's displaying is bad,  Is there anyone meet the same problem?  Please help me.